# Sign in with Apple not showing in signing and comparability menu flutter

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart-pub, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to add sign-in whit apple to my flutter project but when I open Xcode to add it as a *Compatibility* it doesn't show up, and in fact, there are lots of things that are missing.
For example, there is no Apple pay.

So how can I fix this?

I'm using Xcode version 11.5.
Also, the option is not there when creating native IOS app.

[image: All the options that I have]

Comment: What did you opend in XCode?

Comment: @Blasanka I opened my Flutter app, and besides that, I have tried to open one of my previous iOS native apps

Comment: No, opening flutter root directory doesnt work. You must open your flutter project `ios` directory from xcode/

Comment: That is what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capabilities available to an iOS app depend on your program membership.

See: https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev21218dfd6